# Dancer route is appending to current route

Tags: routes, dancer

The route I'd like to generate is:

```
myapp.com/foo/bar
```

Once I hit that route, I can, in the same page that is loaded when hitting that route, go to routes such as:

```
myapp.com/foo/baz
myapp.com/foo/nod
etc
```

So the route that is used to hit the above is:

```
get '/foo/:bar' => sub {
    my $dev = param('bar');
    template 'list', { person => $people };
};
```

In the `list.tt` template, I have a nav list that points again to this route `'foo/:bar'`:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   [% FOREACH person = people%]
         <li><a href="foo/[% person %]">[% person %]</a></li>
   [% END -%]
</ul>
```

My problem is that when I click on one of those links, I get the following in the URL: `'foo/foo/baz'`

Does anyone know why? Should I be explicit when creating my links (i.e. saying `href="myapp.com/foo/[% person %]"`)?

Comment: Can you add how you set $people?

Comment: Your links should start with a '/' if you would like to have absolute links. (like <a href="/abc/[% url %]">)

Comment: @smartmeta you truly are smart :). please set that up as an answer and i'll gladly accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links should start with a '/' if you would like to have absolute links.

like

```
<a href="/abc/[% url %]">
```

HTH